# Is there a Perl ORM with database reverse engineering?

Tags: database, perl, orm

I’m looking for a Perl ORM library that has support for reverse engineering of the database schema. All I’ve found so far is
http://perlorm.sourceforge.net/
and it appears to have no reverse engineering support.

Comment: What do you mean by "reverse engineering"? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I think he means loading the metadata from the database and use it to generate the classes.

Comment: If you can get the schema, there's nothing to engineer. It seems odd to think about an ORM that wouldn't do that. However, I've known people who had to rebuild schema from code.

Comment: Many ORMs require you to do the mapping manually from object to DB, brian.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a [list of recommended ORM modules at the P5P wiki](http://www.perlfoundation.org/perl5/index.cgi?recommended_database_modules).

[Rose::DB::Object](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Rose-DB-Object) and [DBIx::Class](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBIx-Class) can generate classes for you from an existing database schema, and can also write them out to a set of Perl module files.

- [Rose::DB::Object::Loader](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Rose::DB::Object::Loader)
- [DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader)

Answer (score 5):

[DBIx::Class](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBIx-Class) has [DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader) which generates classes for you from an existing datbase and can also write them out to files. It it limited to loading a single schema though.

Answer (score 4):

There are three commonly used ORMs in Perl, [Class:DBI](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Class-DBI/), [DBIx::Class](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBIx-Class/) and [Rose::DB::Object](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Rose-DB-Object/). According to [this](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=700283) page at PerlMonks, they can all load the metadata from the database, but it doesn't say how.