# Python libraries to construct classes from a relational database? (ORM in reverse)

Tags: python, database, orm

Are there any Python object-relational mapping libraries that, given a database schema, can generate a set of Python classes? I know that the major libraries such as [SQLObject](http://www.sqlobject.org/), [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/), and [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/)'s internal SQL ORM library do a very good job of creating a DB schema given a set of classes, but I'm looking for a library that works in reverse.

There is a [related question for Perl libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362929/is-there-a-perl-orm-with-database-reverse-engineering) on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[SQLAlchemy extension to create a python code model from an existing database](http://code.google.com/p/sqlautocode/)

Answer (score 7):

Django had an [inspectdb](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#inspectdb) command that creates models.py files out of your database.

Answer (score 5):

SQLAlchemy can actually do what you want. You can either define the mappings yourself manually using the mapper facility, or auto-generate them using [reflection](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/05/metadata.html#reflecting-tables).

It's not absolutely necessary to build the database using the metadata facility, you can always use an existing one instead.

Answer (score 3):

[Geniusql](http://www.aminus.net/geniusql) (and [Dejavu](http://www.aminus.net/dejavu), its big federated brother) can do that quite well. See "[Automatic Table Classes](http://www.aminus.net/geniusql/chrome/common/doc/trunk/modeling.html)" for the former and "[Automatic Unit Classes](http://www.aminus.net/dejavu/chrome/common/doc/trunk/modeling.html#autoclass)" for the latter.

Answer (score 0):

You can give [algen](https://github.com/danishabdullah/algen) a try:

> Generate opnionated python ORM classes from yaml schema for sqlalchemy